# How to get a parameter form a javascript function as text

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="demo" onclick="applycss(250,500,"red")"></div>
<script>
    function applycss(){
        var box = document.getElementById("this.id").style;
        box.height = fisrt parameter;
        box.width = second parameter;
        box.backgroundColor = third parameter;
    }
</script>
```

How to do this? I want to apply value `250, 500, red` to div on click so that I can use this function to any element without long coding.

Comment: I think before asking syntax questions you should go through a basic javascript tutorial - these basics will be covered there

Comment: You could start with something like [JavaScript basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics) and then [JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide)

Comment: or start with a tutorial like the one's provided by code academy

Comment: Can you use jQuery for it?

Comment: sorry i don't like jQ i like my own coding my own coded liebrary  so please provide me suitable code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax error, see updated code. For multiple CSS properties, you need to create css-string of your parameter values and set it as following:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="demo" onclick="applycss(this, '250', '500', 'red');">Div to apply CSS</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function applycss(obj, height, width, bgColor){
    var cssStyle = "height: " + height + "px; ";
    cssStyle += "width: " + width + "px; ";
    cssStyle += "background-color: " + bgColor + ";";

    if(typeof(obj.style.cssText) != 'undefined')
        obj.style.cssText = cssStyle;
    else
        obj.setAttribute('style', cssStyle);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jn2apf8j/3/)

Comment: Sorry this code is not working i have create div first but did't work then i have replaced div to button but again doe't work please help me

Comment: I'm waiting please help me

Comment: @Vikas Kandari, is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks  Sir  if i have any question i will get back to u :)

Comment: Sure, I will be there to help you.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<script>
     function applycss(fisrt,second,third){
        var box = document.getElementById("demo").style;
          box.height=fisrt;
          box.width=  second;
          box.backgroundColor= third;
}
 </script>
```

Comment: where is the `{}` for the function? also how will the string literal `red` be passed

Comment: oh sorry my misktake please give me resolution  how to do this i'm new in js

Comment: @VikasKandari that is why first you need to go through some tutorials to understand the basic syntax....

Comment: yes i'm learning from internet,youtube,and stackoverflow so i will do it but first please solve this code then i will better understand